# IIf function in Access; establishing hierarchy

Tags: ms-access

I've found a couple answers that are similar to my situation, but I can't seem to adapt them.

I have a form in which people can enter either a Ship To or a Sold To number (two different columns) and then notes. Only a select few of either type will have notes but all records will need to return as part of a larger query. I want to establish a hierarchy with respect to the notes. Basically:

1. If the Sold to is not null and the Ship to is null, return the Sold to notes.
2. If the Ship to is not null and the Sold to is null, return the Ship to notes.
3. If the Ship to is not null and the Sold to is not null, return the Ship to notes.
4. If both are null, do nothing (as in return the field blank)

Is that sufficiently clear? I'm pretty sure I should use the IIf function for this, but I'm not sure beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

`IIf()` would do it, but `Switch()` would be a bit more compact. Try something like this:

```
Switch(Not IsNull([Ship to]), [Ship to notes], Not IsNull([Sold to]), [Sold to notes])
```

For more information on `Switch()`, look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx?CTT=1).

Comment: Actually IIF would be more compact I think. IIf(Not IsNull([Ship to]), [Ship to], [Sold to]). There's no need to test if [Sold to] is Null.

Comment: @TomCollins You missed the fact that it is to return [Ship to notes], [Sold to notes], or Null, depending on the values of [Ship to] and [Sold to] (different fields).

Comment: No, I didn't. If [Ship to] has a value, then I return that, otherwise I return [Sold to], even if [Sold to] is Null.

Comment: @TomCollins You're still not seeing it: It needs to return [Ship to NOTES] or [Sold to NOTES] -- different fields.

Comment: OK, I see what your saying about different fields. Can be read both ways (I was reading it as copy [Ship to] to [notes]), but I think you're right in that they are different fields. But my function logic is still sound. IIf(Not IsNull([Ship to]), [Ship to notes], [Sold to notes]).

Comment: @TomCollins ...unless [Ship to] and [Sold to] are both Null and [Sold to notes] happens to be Not Null....

Comment: OK, point. Although doubtful there would be [Sold to notes] if [Sold to] is null, it is possible.

Comment: Tom, it is possible someone doing data entry could mess up and not include notes but unlikely.

Comment: Thank you both for the input! I'm working on it presently and will let you know if it worked as expected.